# Do I still need to call CoInitialize(NULL) and CoUninitialize() if I switch to ATL?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, atl

Are `CoInitialize(NULL)` and `CoUninitialize()` automatically called by ATL?

Or I still have to call `CoInitialize(NULL)` and `CoUninitialize()` at the beginning and end of my COM application respectively?

Answer (score 2):

In fact you have to call these in every thread in which you want to use COM calls.